# Scaling for specific devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I am running into some issues trying to make my SpriteKit game compatible on all devices. I understand how Image.xcassets works, as well as how to reference the phone frame in placing my nodes.

For example, my game looks fine on 6, 6+ and the iPads. Unfortunately, it has the top the cut off for the earlier iPhones. An easy fix for this would just be to reference the top of the screen like so:

```
node.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) - 5)
```

*This works for all the phones, but not the iPads*

However if I reference the top of the device like that, then on the iPad the upper nodes are too far up the screen such that the hero is not able to interact with them.

The current way my code is written for positioning of nodes is just by using other nodes to build on top of:

```
node.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + node2.size.height + node3.size.height)
```

*This works for the 6, 6+ and the iPads*

How can I make it so there is compatibility on all devices? I Know I could adjust the "2x" image so it could fit for the 5 and 5s, but then it would throw off the game mechanic for 6 (because the 6 and 5 series share the "2x" for some reason).

Is there a way I can specifically test for use on a certain device, and then have certain code run in that case? Are there any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is even easier use a ternary operator operator in Swift:

This checks for sizes of height greater than the iphone 6+ which would mean its' an iPad, then set a custom sized image accordingly, you can even use Lucas' macros he posted above:

```
asdf!.qrImageView.image = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height  > 736 ? UIImage(named: "check") : UIImage(named: "bubbles")
```

Heres' the full code, try this now, obviously change the image to your needs, the call above is using very customized UIView subclass, this next call is not, its using a UIImageView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    var floatiesW = 200 as CGFloat
    var floatiesH = 200 as CGFloat

    var asdf = UIImageView()
    asdf.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    asdf.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.width/2.0) - (floatiesW/2.0), (self.view.bounds.height/2.0) - (floatiesH/2.0), floatiesW, floatiesH)
    asdf.image = self.view.bounds.height  > 736 ? UIImage(named: "check") : UIImage(named: "bubbles")
    self.view.addSubview(asdf)
}
```

and this:

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height  > 736 ? UIImage(named: "check") : UIImage(named: "bubbles")
```

in most cases can be swapped with this:

```
self.view.bounds.height  > 736 ? UIImage(named: "check") : UIImage(named: "bubbles")
```

but be careful, you should probably use the UIScreen.main .. one

Comment: This seems effective and I have tried to implement it in several ways. If I'm not mistaken, the ternary operator functions in a similar manner to a conditional. If so, why do I keep getting an error asking for a declaration? I'm slightly confused on the exact syntactical implementation of this methodology. Thanks, I am very new to programming. @Larcerax

Comment: Not sure what you may be doing wrong or right, but the next best option is to try this, one sec.

Comment: reread the answer I gave you and just drop the code in to see it work

Comment: and you are probably getting a declarearion problem because this call method i gave you is for an IBOutlet with some very customoized constraints, try it now.

Comment: Gonna go ahead and accept your answer, thanks. All of my nodes are declared differently. I.E. as an SKspritenode that references an SKTexture. With that being said It would be hassle to rewrite all of it. Can I just use this same technique with a normal if-statement instead of the ternary operator?

Comment: you sure can, normal if/then statement works just fine

Answer (score 2):

Put this code right below the imports to check to see what kind of device the users are running.

```
enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom1 : Int
{
case Unspecified
case Phone
case Pad
}

struct ScreenSize1
{
static let SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
static let SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH,      ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType1
{
static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS =  UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
static let IS_IPHONE_5 = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
static let IS_IPHONE_6 = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
static let IS_IPHONE_6P = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
}
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` do a simple `if statement` in order to see what device is being used and then run the necessary code under each one.

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0 {
        println("Iphone 4s")
        // put code here
    }
```

And then do this for each device. It is a little tedious obviously but it should do the trick.
Also above I do not have the iPad specifications listed but you can easily provide those just by figuring out the screen height of them. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great. However I'm getting unresolved identifier on "ScreenSize". Do I need to import some kind of other core library? Do I need to declare something for the struct? (Thanks I'm very new) @LucasAzzopardi

Comment: In the code above I have it as ScreenSize1.. change it to that and it should work. or simply change the ScreenSize1 to just ScreenSize